# Fragment appearing behind the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to display a fragment on a CardView click in an activity but the fragment is appearing behind all the CardViews in the activity . Below is the code :

SelectDesignersActivity.java

```
        package com.houssup.userapp;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class SelectDesignersActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,DesignersTabFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        CardView cardView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_five_designers);
            cardView = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card_view1);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        // Let's first dynamically add a fragment into a frame container

                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                                replace(R.id.fragment_container, new DesignersTabFragment(), "SOMETAG").
                                commit();
                        // Now later we can lookup the fragment by tag
                    }

                }
            });
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.select_designers, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

        }
    }
```

activity_five_designers.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_five_designers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        </include>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_five_designers"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_five_designers_drawer" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

DesignersTabFragment.java

```
        package com.houssup.userapp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
     * {@link DesignersTabFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
     * to handle interaction events.
     * Use the {@link DesignersTabFragment#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class DesignersTabFragment extends Fragment {
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;

        private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

        public DesignersTabFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment DesignersTabFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static DesignersTabFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            DesignersTabFragment fragment = new DesignersTabFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_designers_tab, container, false);
        }

        // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
        public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mListener = null;
        }

        /**
         * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
         * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
         * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
         * activity.
         * <p>
         * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
         * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
         * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
         */
        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            // TODO: Update argument type and name
            void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
        }
    }
```

I have included the FrameLayout for the fragment in activity_five_designers.xml . But the fragment appears behind all the cardviews . I want to show only the fragment with the navigation drawer of the activity.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you change place between app_bar_five_designers and fragment_container, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_five_designers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </include>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_five_designers"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_five_designers_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The first child will be in background, and the last one will be in foreground

Comment: Though the issue resolved but now the toolbar is not appearing which I need for the navigation drawer

Comment: When fragment is not displayed, set visibility to INVISIBLE for the frameLayout

Comment: No , Actually on the activity it is being displayed , but I want that same toolbar on the fragment also with the triple bar icon for the same navigation drawer !!

Comment: You should make activity with all the stuff you want in commun. And the part which need to be updated should be two different fragments

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your frame layout below toolbar in order to see your toolbar

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_five_designers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```